Add a row to a Google sheet when a user creates a new file in a specific shared drive
Each user has a specific Google shared drive setup for them to create and edit files. We are hoping to setup an activity log so that when a user creates a new file in their specific Google Shared Drive it would update a Google Sheet. Ideally need the date and time stamp to be added to one of the cells. The Google sheet column titles would be something like this
Date and time file created / Name of file / Location of file / Email address of user
We would have an automatic trigger to check this every few minutes
I am new to this aspect of Google app scripts  so apologies for no code examples. I am hoping there is a Googgle app script that can achieve this.

In order to solve your query on adding a row when a user creates a new file in a specific shared drive, Either a Simple Trigger or Installable Trigger must be used on the script.
But according to the official documentation of Simple Triggers, it shows that there are no available trigger specifically for Google Drive.
Here is a screenshot showing the Availability type of triggers on the documentation:


Possible Workaround
You may use Time-based triggers but the update will not be real time and there is a possibility of trigger quota if you set the time trigger on a short time period.

References

Available types of triggers
Simple Triggers
Quotas for Google Services


Thanks for the info. is there the option if the specific user creates a new folder - that it can still add a row in a sheet with the information?

@ExeterTrees Sadly, creating a new folder would still fall under Google Drive functions. So that is still not possible with Simple Triggers and Installable Triggers.  The only possible workaround is what's written on the answer above, using Time-based triggers.
